# Подкорректировать regular expression

Tags: c#

Написал вот такую регулярку.

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^\+\d{5,15}$|\(|\)|-");
```

Предпологая вот такие вводы:

```
+38(000)000-94-12
+38(000)0009412
8(000)000-94-12
(000)000-94-12
```

---

Подскажите, что нужно дописать что бы избавиться от вот таких ошибок ввода:

```
+38(sds)0949412
+38(096)342-ss-97
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?([-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*)?((\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{2,4})(?:[-.x ]*(\d+))?)\s*$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 ^\+?\d*\(\d{3}\)[\d-]+$
```

[fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/UHeDH5/1)

или, чтобы избежать телефонов типа `+(123)456-78-90`,

```
^((\+?\d+)|(\d*))\(\d{3}\)[\d-]+$
```

[fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/UHeDH5/2)